# How to add Parse event recording to a custom iOS framework?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, frameworks

I want to add Parse.com event recording to my iOS app's custom framework. I have followed [Parse's instructions](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/events/mobile/ios/swift/existing), except I add the Parse and other required frameworks to my framework, rather than to my app. Everything is fine until I add the "import Parse" line to one of the files in my framework (the one I'm trying to add Parse to), at which point the compiler tells me "No such module 'Parse'". Cleaning and rebuilding (and trashing Derived Data, cleaning, and rebuilding) have the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to get Pare.com working inside your Framework? I am having some issues too. Thanks.

Comment: I did. Please see the answer I added to this question (i.e., the gist below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem and the solution is documented at https://gist.github.com/multinormal/206e72ec4bdd5990d4d8

Comment: Did you use Cocoapods to install the Parse framework or downloading it from Parse.com?

Comment: The solution is not that long. You should include it here, because right now your answer is a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you create an objective-c bridging header (because of the tag, I'll assume you are programming in swift) 
You can create a header by simply creating a new objective-c file and it will prompt you to create a new bridging header.

For more detailed instructions, see the following:

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I don't *think* it's a bridging header problem (though not 100% sure). I'm in the process of making a framework that just wraps the Parse functionality, and following the same steps as above seems to work fine. It looks like I need to be a bit cunning because one can't include delis in frameworks that are included in app extensions. I think I can route around that.